# When IQueryable returns no record ToList() throws an exception

Tags: linq, exception, null, iqueryable

```
dataContext.Geo_Countries.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchKey)).ToList<Geo_Country>();
```

when the IQueryable returns no records, I get a value null exception.

What is the solution?

Comment: There is something else going on then, because normally you should not get a null exception from the statement you posted unless dataContext or Geo_Countries is null.  You may need to post more information, such as what linq provider you are using...

Comment: You should not get an exception on that..unless you are trying to evaluate the results of that query.

Comment: Using the Northwind database & LINQPad, I ran this: `Categories.Where(c=>c.CategoryName=="XXXX").ToList().Dump();` and it worked fine, returning an empty list.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you don't get the problem when there are no matches - I suspect you get it when there's a row in your database with no `Name` value. Either that, or you're doing something else which you haven't shown us. What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: text

Source Error: 
Line 69:         public List<Geo_Country> SearchCountriesByName(String searchKey)
Line 70:         {
Line 71:             return _dc.Geo_Countries.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(searchKey)).ToList();
Line 72:         }
Line 73: 
 
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   OD.Domain.Repositories.GeoRepository.SearchCountriesByName(String searchKey) in F:\OD\OD.Domain\Repositories\GeoRepository.cs:71

Comment: @Doozie: Is `searchKey` null by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

try to use this code

```
dataContext.Geo_Countries.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(searchKey)).ToList();
```

Comment: That did not help. I have only two records in the table those countries are "United States" and "Canada", and my searchKey is "li". There are no records with null or white space etc.

Comment: May be dataContext or Geo_Countries is null. Could you check it in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Calling ToList() on IQueryable will throw an exception if code doesn't properly execute. In the following example, ToList() will throw an exception if c.Name is null:

```
void Main()
{
    var countries = new [] { new Country() }.AsQueryable();
    countries.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("bubba")).ToList();
}


class Country{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```