# Java program to get all class level dependencies in a jar

Tags: java, class, jar, dependencies, package

I am trying to list every class name being used in a jar, even the ones being used from import statements. I would like a programmatic way to find this solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417820/how-to-list-dependencies-of-a-jar) helps

Comment: That gets the results, but i need a programmatic way to do it and not use a standalone utility