# How do I check if a Linux machine is using apache common text library

Tags: linux

I would like to to know what command I can use to check if [apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) common text library is used on a Linux machine.

Using `ldconfig -p | grep org.apache.commons:commons-text` gives no results

Comment: You can't do that with "linux" tools, since apache commons is a java library, and is actually cross-platform. You can use some java-specific tools, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417820/how-to-list-dependencies-of-a-jar , but you'll have to process every jar file that you have on this machine. What are you trying to achieve? Do you know what kind of applications are and where they are deployed on your servers? What application servers are you using, if any? Do you have a source code of your applications to scan their dependencies there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

locate -b -e -r'^commons-text.*.jar$'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).